# Curve along two edges on plane

Tags: bezier-curves, edges

I'm new to Blender (v2.77) and I'm working on an automobile door window.

I have a plane where I'd like to create a curve for the window connected to two edges.

[image: Blender curve along two edges]

Ideally, as seen in the photo, "A" & "B" edges would be removed and the black line would be the new curve.

I tried beveling the vertex at the intersection but naturally, it creates a diamond pattern rather than making a curve between the A+B edges.

Thank you for reading and I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using subsurf on your mesh?

Comment: Please show the result you do not like in a screen capture.  If you unable to have multiple pics in your question, consider combining the images with open free software such as GIMP.  Of course Blender can combine images with arguably more work.

Comment: Are you concerned about Blender 3D View appearance?  Is Render appearance more important?  You may want to look up Ngon where polygons do not show all their internal triangle lines.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh There currently isn't subsurf on the mech. This is technically for a low poly rendering and it won't be animated but for practice, I'd like the cleanest method possible.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I don't have a result because I can't create it :) Currently, I am using the knife tool and manually creating a curve and then creating edges back up to the intersection of A+B but it seems silly to do this method. Rendering is more important per se but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extrude whole selection

Delete inner segments and bridge gap

Now bevel edge and delete excess afterwards.

Follow up with an n-gon or grid fill.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use low poly modelisation. If you want to take care about topology (and you probably should), avoid N-gons (and triangles).

Subdivision Surface modifier allow you make curves without have to manage too much geometry. I just added 2 loops for control the modifier :

[image: Jus]

For more control add, more geometry, but try to keep a good toplogy. Adapt the toplogy to your model : depending of your needs, it can be better to redirect the geomety like this :

[image]

For positionning your vertices in a curve, the LoopTools plugin is very helpfull :

- Ctrl - Alt - U -> Add-ons -> serach LoopTools and activate.
- Select your vertices
- W  ->  LoppTools -> Relax